# Creation of Text file using web service in same directory using C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want  to create a text file using C#.net in the same directory in which the file reside.
what is the solution? 
When i am trying to create i got error "Access to the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\test.txt' is denied". please help.

Thanks

Comment: Create an acceible folder to put the files in, you do not want to put text files where your executable is.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to create the file in the same directory as is the web service directory, because when you create for example new StreamWriter("test.txt"), it creates the file in the current **working** directory of the process (ASP.NET / IIS).

Comment: what is the solution . please

Answer (score 0):

Use Server.MapPath('~\test.text')

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by windows permissions where you are not allowed to create files on your 'c' drive. Or a folder has certain access rights assigned to them. Try changing the permissions or right to another file to find out.